# How to remove filtering from Angular UI-Grid

Tags: angular-ui-grid

I want to display a grid with no filters on the header using angular ui grid.Currently with the below code im getting filters at the column header.

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope','$http', function ($scope,$http) { 
      $scope.gridOptions = {};
      $http.get('data/grid1.json')
      .success(function(data) {
        $scope.gridOptions.data = data;
      });
}]);
```

Below is the HTML where the grid is loaded

```
<div id="grid1" ui-grid="gridOptions" class="grid"></div>
```

here is a sample how it looks like
  http://ui-grid.info/

Could anybody suggest me  how to remove these filters

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to remove a filter for a single column only, columnDefs should specify

```
enableFiltering
```

I often do this with an extra column that I add for actions:

```
var actionCol = {
    name: 'Actions',
    width: '90',
    cellTemplate: actionTemplate,
    enableCellEdit: false,
    sortable: false,
    enableFiltering: false
};
```

Reference: [UI-Grid API](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.class:GridOptions#enableFiltering)

Answer (score 0):

To remove the filter options, you need to configure the grid with   enableFiltering: false .

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
  enableFiltering: false
};
```